# How to open postgres command Line?

Tags: windows, postgresql, command-line

I have postgres installed.How to open postgres command Line?
When i open command prompt, i have

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.590]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\dhanr>
```

How to navigate to postgres command Line, as my final goal is to run `pg_dump dbname > outfile` command.

Comment: You need to have postgres executable on your Path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use psql command-line tool.

You can find psql at your installation directory. Example;

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin\psql.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

Go inside bin folder in C drive where Postgres is installed. run following command in git bash or Command prompt: pg_ctl.exe restart -D "" Ex: pg_ctl.exe restart -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\data"

Another way: type "services.msc" in run popup(windows + R). This will show all services running Select Postgres service from list and click on start/stop/restart.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.It will restart the service.. I was looking for command Line